# Do SSD still need supercapacitor today ? (NAS : Linux + MDADM + EXT4)

Tags: linux, mdadm, ssd, network-attached-storage, ext4

I'm planning to build a SSD based NAS, with Linux / mdadm / EXT4 (so, no ZFS or Btrfs).

What happens in case of a sudden power loss ? There are a lot of posts out there stating that we should buy SSDs with supercapacitors, but all those posts are fairly old (2010's).

Is this advice still relevant today ?

SATA 2.5" SSD with supercap can be found. But what about NVMe's ? Let's say for example I plan to buy [an Asus Flashstor](https://www.asustor.com/en/product?p_id=79). What happens in case of a powerloss ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A buffer battery or supercap is required to avoid losing data *in the cache* that hasn't been written to disk yet. While SSDs are fast (NVMe more so than SAS or SATA), they can't be updated in zero time.

So yes, buffering cache memory is still a good thing if your data is precious. Depending on your requirements you should also consider a UPS.

Comment: I guess SSDs in laptops are naturally protected, thanks to the battery. Am I right ?

Comment: Laptops effectively have a builtin UPS, yes.

Comment: Sure, but laptops ain't on topic here...

Comment: @ChennyStar: Assuming the power failure is *before* the battery. If the power failure is *after* the battery, it does not help.

Comment: If a laptop isn't configured to shut down or sleep when there is a low battery condition, no not really.

Comment: And what happens if I brutally shut down a laptop (usually by long pressing the power button) ? Does it behave like a power failure ? Or do the SSD drives still use the battery's energy to finish what they have to do ?

Comment: @ChennyStar Good question - M.2 is supposed to power the SSD from standby 3.3V, so it should be able to write back its internal cache. SATA usually only provides 5V/12V, without standby power, so it'd need to bring its own battery or supercap, or rely on a proprietary solution.

Comment: @Zac67: Interesting about M.2, I didn't know that. It seems Micron are the only ones advertising about it, calling it "Power loss protection for data-at-rest" (https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/ssd/m550_m2_2280_ssd.pdf) , but the general opinion seems indeed to be that all manufacturers include in in one way or another (https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/microns-power-loss-protection-for-data-at-rest.39928/, https://hardforum.com/threads/data-at-rest-and-unexpected-power-loss.2000419/).

Comment: So,  basically that means I shouldn't need to worry too much because of power loss on an all M.2/NVMe/SSD NAS. It would be nice though if SSD manufacturers advertised it more overtly. I'm not 100% convinced that all SSD have PLP (power loss protection). Otherwise, why would there be the need for USB enclosures with integrated 5 seconds PLP, like https://www.amazon.com/DOCKCASE-Visual-Enclosure-Support-Prevents/dp/B09Z2CFDYQ/).

Comment: @ChennyStar Supplying standby power doesn't protect the cache from mains failure, only for the force-off scenario detailed above. Any vendor advertising such a feature would need to actually provide hardware, like a supercap.

Comment: OK, I didn't get it. So, what you said in your last comment was that, in a laptop with standby power (battery), M.2 devices are protected against a forceful shutdown, but not SATA devices. Do I understand correctly ?

Comment: @ChennyStar That's correct - I wasn't specifically talking about off-topic laptops though. ;-)

Comment: That leaves us with the question about what exactly Micron's "Power loss protection for data-at-rest" brings to the table...

Comment: Question answered here : https://sabrent.com/blogs/storage/power-loss. It makes for an interesting read, explaining the difference between data-at-rest and data-in-flight. Basically all SSD's have data-at-rest protection, Micron emphasizing it is just marketing blabla. What's needed to fully protect agains power loss is data-in-flight protection, and that's only provided by capacitors (or external UPS).